# Vapor HTTPClient follow redirect

Tags: swift, vapor

I can't figure out how to follow redirects from an external URL. The URL I am accessing is for some reason giving me 301, even though I don't get it in postman. I am wondering how I can get HTTPClient to follow the redirect or if I am doing anything wrong in order to get a 301.

I did read [this PR](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/pull/1480), but I don't think it is relevant anymore. Nor does the [HTTPClient documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/http/client/) cover redirects.
In the example below I've set the User-Agent to the same as Postman, in order to mimic Postman's request as much as possible.

My code so far:

```
import Vapor
import HTTP

protocol DataFetching {
  func getFromURL(_ url: URL, on worker: Worker) throws -> Future<HTTPResponse>
}

class DataFetcher: DataFetching {

  enum Error: Swift.Error {
    case unknown
  }

  func getFromURL(_ url: URL, on worker: Worker) throws -> Future<HTTPResponse> {

    guard let host = url.host else { throw Error.unknown }

    var headers = HTTPHeaders()
    headers.replaceOrAdd(name: .userAgent, value: "PostmanRuntime/7.4.0")
    headers.replaceOrAdd(name: .accept, value: "*/*")
    headers.replaceOrAdd(name: .cacheControl, value: "no-cache")
    headers.replaceOrAdd(name: .applyToRedirectRef, value: "true")
    headers.replaceOrAdd(name: .acceptEncoding, value: "gzip, deflate")

    let httpRequest = HTTPRequest(method: .GET, url: url, version: HTTPVersion(major: 1, minor: 1), headers: headers)

    return HTTPClient.connect(hostname: host, on: worker).flatMap { client in
      return client.send(httpRequest)
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is because `URLRequest` doesn't follow 301 redirects (it does follow 302). You might be able to register a custom `FoundationClient` instance with your app's services.

Comment: Thnx. I ended up using `URLSession` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using URLSession instead. This is my endresult which works well for me:

```
enum DataFetcherErrors: Error {
  case didNotRecieveData
  case unknown
}

protocol DataFetching {
  func getFromURL(_ url: URL, on worker: Worker) throws -> Future<Data>
}

class DataFetcher: DataFetching {

  let urlSession: URLSession
  private var headers = [
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "DataFetcher",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"
  ]

  init(urlSession: URLSession = .shared) {
    self.urlSession = urlSession
  }

  func getFromURL(_ url: URL, on worker: Worker) throws -> Future<Data> {
    let promise = worker.eventLoop.newPromise(Data.self)

    request(url: url) { (data, response, error) in
      if let error = error {
        promise.fail(error: error)
      }

      guard let data = data else {
        promise.fail(error: DataFetcherErrors.didNotRecieveData)
        return
      }

      promise.succeed(result: data)
    }

    return promise.futureResult
  }
}

private extension DataFetcher {

  func request(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping ((Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    headers.forEach { fieldName, value in
      request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: fieldName)
    }

    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    task.resume()
  }
}
```